# Convert KMeans Labels into Source data in Sklearn

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN, MiniBatchKMeans
data = np.random.rand(5,5)
print data
km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=10, max_iter=5)
km.fit(data)
labels = km.labels_
print labels
[1 2 0 2 2]
```

How can I reconstruct my data using the labels? I mean making my data composed of labels in each pixel.

Comment: Try to clarify your question. Why isn't ``labels`` what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndreasMueller because the data are in (5,5) shapes. I also want the labels in the same (5,5) shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do 1d clustering, then reshape your data to a 1d array, cluster the points and then reshape back your labels:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
data_to_cluster = np.reshape(data, (data.size, 1))

km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=10, max_iter=5)
km.fit(data_to_cluster)

labels = km.labels_
labels = np.reshape(labels, (5, 5))
```

Comment: What does output1 do? It is just ``labels.reshape(-1, 1)``, right?

Comment: `np.tile()` repeat the vector so that he gets a matrix of the shape of data.

Comment: @AndreasMueller But each pixel should correspond to the correct label, is it done by this solution everytime?

Comment: @jean You are clustering the vectors, not the "pixels". If you want to do 1D clustering then reshape your data to a vector of shape (25, 1), but I can't understand why you would do 1D clustering.

Comment: @Hugo, AndreasMueller. I am doing 2d clustering, so the result also want in 2d. The pixels belonging to same clusters will propagate thae same label value

Comment: @jean You are doing 1d clustering of every pixels of an image. So reshape your image as 1d vector. Then cluster every pixels and then reshape the labels to the initial shape.

Comment: @Hugo So with out reshaping, what my example in question did? 2d?

Comment: @jean I edited my answer. I hope it is what you wanted.